# Speech recognition english corpuses

Tags: nlp, audio

Could someone provide a list (or link to) of english speech recognition corpuses with their availability and size (preferably in hours).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. List: http://kaldi-asr.org/doc/examples.html ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170924050745/http://www.kaldi-asr.org:80/doc/examples.html))
2. List: https://voice.mozilla.org/en/data:

   [image]
3. Corpus: https://voice.mozilla.org/en